# Read CSV file into sqlite3 on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, csv, sqlite

Is there a way to read a CSV file into sqlite3 on the iPhone?  Is there sqlite3 functionality similar to the SQL commands

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE TABLENAME FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Or is there an approach that converts the CSV file into a format that sqlite3 can read automatically which the iPhone brings up the application?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214000/read-large-file-into-sqlite-table-in-objective-c-on-iphone

Comment: Yes, that is true.  This question was asked in a response to the main question you've linked to above.  So I thought that if I turned it into a separate question it would be easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

You can read CSV and other files into your DB using Core Data but I dont think that is going to help you as it sounds like you have started developing using Sqlite

Answer (score 1):

you can try the firefox addon "SQLITE MANAGER" wich has an option to import data from CSV.

[SQLITE Manager for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817)